# use of ismember or intersect in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two column vectors [a b] and [c d]. I want to select only those data points in 'a'where 'c' matches to 'a' and also corresponding 'b' values. As there is some repetition in 'a' which is making 'ismember' command not to work properly. 'For loop' is another option but size of column vectors is too big for making a loop. Just short example is given below. Any solution? Thanks

> > [a b]

ans =

```
1.0000    0.1000
2.0000    0.2000
2.0000    0.2000
3.0000    0.4000
4.0000    0.5000
```

> > [c d]

ans =

```
 2     7
 3    12
```

Comment: What it your desired output?

Comment: If you have a working for-loop version of your code, posting that in the question would make it easier for everybody to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If repeated values for `a` always come with the same value for `b`, you can use the second output of `ismember` for a simple solution:

```
ab=[1.0000    0.1000
2.0000    0.2000
2.0000    0.2000
3.0000    0.4000
4.0000    0.5000];
cd=[2     7
3    12];


[~,idx]=ismember(cd(:,1),ab(:,1))
out = ab(idx,:)

out =

    2.0000    0.2000
    3.0000    0.4000
```

If repeated values for `a` sometimes can have different values for `b` (e.g. `[2 0.2; 2 0.3]`, you need to call `unique` on `a` first:

```
[~,idx] = unique(ab(:,1));
ab = ab(idx,:);
out = ab(ismember(ab(:,1),cd(:,1)),:);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly the solution is to start with:

```
[a idx] = unique(a);
b = b(idx);
```

This way you removed all duplicate occurances of a, so now you can just use your regular methods like `ismember` or `intersect`.

Comment: Did you mean b = b(idx)?

Comment: @Sunil Thanks, the reverse indeed won't do much. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was a little unclear. I am assuming your desired output is:

```
2.0000    0.2000
2.0000    0.2000
3.0000    0.4000
```

I defined your matrices like this:

```
AB = [a b];
CD = [c d];
```

Using ismember:

```
ismember(AB(:,1), CD(:,1)); % Compare first columns.
```

will give you the row numbers. Like this:

```
 0
 1
 1
 1
 0
```

So, what you need to do is:

```
AB(ismember(AB(:,1), CD(:,1)),:); % Get the entire corresponding row.
```

The output will be:

```
2.0000    0.2000
2.0000    0.2000
3.0000    0.4000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but desired output is rejecting the repeated one. Like '2.000' should come only one time not twice.

Comment: @user1949014 In that case, please show the correct output for your example.

Comment: @userEitanT 
>> output 
1st column 2.0000 3.0000
2nd column 0.2000 0.4000

Comment: @user1949014 So just add `unique(X, 'rows')` on the result `X`.